# Nhibernate Mapping on two columns on join

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

---

Check

```
<class name="Blankhol" table="hoL" lazy="false">

    <id name="Id" column="H_Id" />

    <property name="MId" column="M_ID" insert="false" update="false" />


    <many-to-one name="MemInfo"
                 class="BusinessDataEntities.Domain.Net.Company, BusinessDataEntities"
                 lazy="false">
      <column name="M_ID" />
    </many-to-one>

    <join table="[Network]">
      <key column="H_Id" />
      <property name="NId" column="N_Id" insert="false" update="false"/>
    </join>

    <join table="[H_Outer]" optional="true">
      <key column="H_Id" />
    <property name="APS" column="AMPS_Prs" insert="false" update="false" />
      <property name="NId" column="N_Id" insert="false" update="false"/>
    </join>


  </class>
```

currently my join is on Id and my query looks like

```
Select * from h where h.id= N_Id.id
```

I want some thing like this

```
Select * from h
where h.id= N_Id.id and h.N_Id= ol.N_Id
```

Any one can help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [NHibernate Mapping multiple tables to one class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863668/nhibernate-mapping-multiple-tables-to-one-class)