# NHibernate Mapping multiple tables to one class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

In my legacy Database I have a situation like this:

```
TableA (id_A[PK], cod_A)
TableB (id_B[PK], cod_B, id_A[FK])
TableC (id_C[PK], cod_C, id_B[FK])
```

For several reasons I need to map these tables into a single class (Foo in this example)

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual string IdA { get; set; }
    public virtual string CodA { get; set; }

    public virtual string IdB { get; set; }
    public virtual string CodB { get; set; }

    public virtual string IdC { get; set; }
    public virtual string CodC { get; set; }    
}
```

By the following mapping I'm able to join Table1 and Table2 but not Table3

```
<class name="Foo" table="TableA">

    <id name="IdA" column="id_A"/>
    <property name="CodA" column="cod_A"/> 

    <join table="TableB">
      <key column="id_A"/>
      <property name="IdB" column="id_B"/>
      <property name="CodB" column="cod_B"/>      
    </join>

    <!--Here my problem because off course the join will be on TableA instead on TableB-->
    <join table="TableC">
      <key column="id_B"/>
      <property name="IdC" column="id_C"/>
      <property name="CodC" column="cod_C"/>      
    </join>

  </class>
```

How can I map Table3?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What NH version are you using? Can you add the SQL query you receive?

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate discourage you to use join as much as possible. But some times there is no way around it.

The first and easiest way to solve it, if you can, is to create a view and map your class to the view.

Second way, is to create an object to each of the other tables and connect them in the proper way, probably - `<one-to-one>` mapping.

Third way

*** Warning - proceed at your own risk ***

Download NH source code - https://github.com/Nicaog/nhibernate-core/downloads.

Download the following bug patch fix instructions - https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1681

Change the code, compile the DLL and add it to your solution.

Explanation - The patch actully fix using `property-ref` for `<join>` mapping. *but also using multiple join with `property-ref`.*

Comment: At the end I realized that it's not possible to map multiple join tables on a single class. As you suggested I solved the problem using a view. Unfortunately this solution is not the best for my purpose. Thanks.

Comment: There is a third way, a complicated one which I used to join multiple tables, but it involved to make changes to NH DLL.

Comment: It's a good idea. Could you briefly explain to me what you changed for joining multiple tables? Thanks

Comment: I can add it to my answer, but be warned, this is a dangerous operation, that might not be supported in future versions!

Comment: I already tried the NH-1681 patch but it's just to change the column name (you can join other column instead the PK only) and not the table name.
A possible solution would be permit nested <join> but I didn't find any patch for that.

Comment: Using property-ref in the key tag, allows me the use multiple join statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<id name="IdA" column="id_A"/>
<property name="CodA" column="cod_A"/> 

<join table="TableB">
  <key column="id_A"/>
  <property name="IdB" column="id_B"/>
  <property name="CodB" column="cod_B"/>   

  <join table="TableC">
  <key column="id_B"/>
  <property name="IdC" column="id_C"/>
  <property name="CodC" column="cod_C"/>      
  </join>
</join>
```

Are you able to do this?

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation as to ***why*** this is the answer.